# Excel - Lookup data in another sheet

Tags: excel, datatable, vlookup

I have the following dataset on Sheet 1:

```
ISBN        CType   CID     FullName
1234567890  A01             John Smith
1275910285  A07             Joe Bloggs
7885419987  A01             Bob Thornton
```

I also have the following information on Sheet 2

```
CID         FullName
7895123675  John Smith
4210326985  Joe Bloggs
75126548951 Bob Thornton
```

What I want is a formula or code that can do the following:

The code will look at the `FullName` in Sheet 1 (55,000 Records) and in reference to sheet 2 (22,000 Records), it will search for the relevant `FullName` (22,000 unique records when it has the combination of `CID` and `FullName`) and populate the `CID` in Sheet 1 with the `CID` from Sheet 2.

I have tried to use the `VLookUp` function however it hasn't worked at all!

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I could get vlookup to work either, because the data you're looking for is to the right of the data you want to return. I just learned how to do what you need using match() and offset() from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20959318/google-spreadsheet-look-up-cell-based-on-value-of-other). This function would need to go in the CID column in Sheet1:

```
    =OFFSET(Sheet2!$A$1,MATCH(D2,Sheet2!B:B,0)-1,0)
```

I used the absolute reference ("$A$1") so you could drag down the formula without that changing. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the simple `LOOKUP` function?

I'll assume that the first blank space in Sheet1 (the CID for John Smith) is cell C2.

You can simply put this expression into that space:

```
=LOOKUP(C3,Sheet2!B$2:B$22001,Sheet2!A$2:A$22001)
```

and then copy/paste it into all the other blank cells.